# Ruby on Rails - Redmine plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I am looking for help to configure Redmine-Plugin further. The Redhopper plugin is ok but it displays all of the issues not regarding if the Sprint is already closed. I have already looked for information on Google but didn't find any.

I put the code of the class where I think it should be configured.

- There is a table called `versions` with a column `status` and 3 options (open, block, closed).
- In table `issues` there is a column `fixed_version_id` which contains the `versions_id`
- The KanbanBoard should then display only the issues with `version.status = open`.

If you need extra information, do let me know.

Thanks in advance.

```
class KanbanBoard
  attr_reader :columns

  def initialize project
    @project = project
    @columns_by_status = {}

    @columns = statuses.map do |status|
      @columns_by_status[status] = Column.new status
    end

    project_issues = issues

    RedhopperIssue.ordered.each do |redhopper_issue|
      issue = redhopper_issue.issue
      if project_issues.include?(issue)
        column_for_issue_status(issue.status) << redhopper_issue
        project_issues.delete issue
      end
    end

    project_issues.each do |issue|
      column_for_issue_status(issue.status) << RedhopperIssue.new(issue: issue)
    end
  end

  private

  def column_for_issue_status status
    @columns_by_status[status]
  end

  def issues
    project_issues = Issue.visible(User.current, :project => @project)
    project_issues = project_issues.open if Feature.enabled("only_open_statuses")
    project_issues = project_issues.where(tracker_id: tracker_ids)

    project_issues.to_a
  end

  def tracker_ids
    trackers_to_remove = (Setting.plugin_redhopper && Setting.plugin_redhopper["hidden_tracker_ids"] || []).map(&:to_i)

    @project.trackers.map(&:id) - trackers_to_remove
  end

  def statuses
    result = IssueStatus.sorted
    result = result.where(is_closed: false) if Feature.enabled("only_open_statuses")

    necessary_statuses = []
    WorkflowTransition.where(:tracker_id => tracker_ids, :role_id => Role.all.map(&:id)).each do |transition|
      necessary_statuses << transition.old_status
      necessary_statuses << transition.new_status
    end

    result & necessary_statuses.uniq
  end
end
```

Code in Issue model:

```
class RedhopperIssue < ActiveRecord::Base
  unloadable
  resort!

  belongs_to :issue
  attr_accessible :issue

  validates :issue, uniqueness: true

  def blocked_with_comment?
    blocked?
  end

  def blockers
    issue.relations_to.select {|ir| ir.relation_type == IssueRelation::TYPE_BLOCKS && ir.other_issue(issue).visible?}.map { |ir| ir.issue_from }
  end

  def blocked_with_issues?
    blockers.present?
  end

  def blocked_issues
    issue.relations_from.select {|ir| ir.relation_type == IssueRelation::TYPE_BLOCKS && ir.other_issue(issue).visible?}.map { |ir| ir.issue_to }
  end

  def blocking_issue?
    blocked_issues.present?
  end

  def comments
    # Some issue updates set notes to nil or "" hence the inline SQL :(
    issue.journals.visible.where("LENGTH(journals.notes) > 0")
  end

  def sortable?
    persisted?
  end

  def due_delta
    issue.due_before ? DueDeltaPresenter.new(issue.due_before) : nil
  end

  # Presenter

  def highlight_class
    blocked_with_issues? ? 'highlight_warning' : blocking_issue? || blocked_with_comment? ? 'highlight_danger' : ''
  end

  def tracker_color
    "##{Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(issue.tracker.id.to_s)[0..5]}"
  end
end
```

I have already tried Feature.enabled("only_open_statuses") enable. This option hides the column `closed`. But I would like to see which Issues were already closed in the current Sprint. I am a PHP Programmer. I think in Rails should be somethink like (line #5):

```
def issues
    project_issues = Issue.visible(User.current, :project => @project) 
    project_issues = project_issues.open if Feature.enabled("only_open_statuses")
    project_issues = project_issues.where(tracker_id: tracker_ids) 
    project_issues = project_versions.where(status: 'open')

    project_issues.to_a
  end
```

Comment: What is in the `Issue` model? All you need to do is update the `issues` method to chain an additional filter on the model.

Comment: By the way, a *very* well-conformed-to style guide in ruby is to [use 2-space soft tabs, not hard tabs](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#source-code-layout). You'll find it much easier to integrate your code with other people's if you conform to that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The code is not from me. It belongs a plugin called Redhopper. I added to my question the code in the Issue model.

Comment: Ahh ok, I get it now. I've done a little digging into the source code, and long story short it looks like all you need to do is enable `Feature.enabled("only_open_statuses")`. Have you done that already (or are you confused how?) Note that this will also include `blocked` issues as well as `open`, but I think that's better.

Comment: A couple of reference links, in case anyone wants a head start researching this in the absence of me posting a full answer (yet): https://framagit.org/infopiiaf/redhopper/blob/master/app/models/feature.rb and https://svn.redmine.org/redmine/branches/3.3-stable/app/models/issue.rb